# SQL Server Indexing Strategy

Tags: sql-server, indexing, partitioning, clustered-index

I'm building a web application using SQL Server 2008 and am having difficulty coming up with the best indexing strategy given our use-case. For example, most of the tables are structured similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Jobs 
(
   Id int identity(0, 1) not null,
   CmpyId int not null default (0),
   StatusId int not null default (0),
   Name nvarchar(100) null,
   IsDeleted bit not null default (0),

   CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Jobs] 
      PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id ASC))

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Jobs_CmpyIdAndId 
    ON Jobs (CmpyId, Id)

CREATE INDEX IX_Jobs_CmpyIdAndStatusId 
   ON Jobs (CmpyId, StatusId)
```

In our application, users are separated into different companies which results in nearly all queries looking similar to the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Jobs 
WHERE CmpyId = @cmpyId AND ...
```

Additionally, jobs are frequently accessed by `StatusId` (canceled = -1, pending = 0, open = 1, assigned = 2, closed = 3), similar to the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Jobs 
WHERE CmpyId = @cmpyId 
  AND StatusId >= 0 
  AND StatusId < 3
```

Would I be better off using the composite clustered index as shown above, or should I use the default clustered index on the `Id` field only and create a separate index for `CmpyId`?

For the `StatusId` column, would I be correct in assuming a filtered index would be the way to go?

I'm also considering partitioning the table by `CmpyId` or `StatusId`, but not sure which would be best (or if no partition is best).

Comment: General speaking is best for clustered index to be as simple and compact possible. In your case I would keep the clustered index to `Id` and create a nonclustered index on `CmpnId`. `StatusId` since can have only 5 values I suspect that will have low selectivity, so an index on that I guess will not lead to better performance.

Comment: Just a side-note: **always** name constraints yourself. If you leave it up to SQL Server it will assign a random name to it. It can be hell when you later decide to modify database structure using SQL scripting since you don't have the proper names. In this case I'm referring to the `DEFAULT` constraints you have in your table definition.

Comment: There are two threads on dba.stackexchange.com that can offer valuable insights. [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108881/should-the-index-on-an-identity-column-be-nonclustered) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7741/when-should-a-primary-key-be-declared-non-clustered).

Comment: Also for `StatusId` I would use `tinyint` to save 3 bytes from the row.

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda premature optimization. You can spend a lot of time worrying about which one will net you a slightly faster database, but when you are live in production, is when you will have best chance of optimizing your indexes.

SQL Server has traces to see which queries are being ran the most and taking the longest. You can test out different indexing strategies when its live in production with almost no risk.  At worst you can slow your application down.

I typically setup clustered indexes on the primary key. And non clustered on all important columns. This works good for the JVM stack that is used with the SQL Server. You don't know where the bottle necks are going to be without having data to see it.

Comment: Generally speaking, I would agree. However at this phase we are building our application which means our code can be molded around our database schema. Since our production tables will grow very rapidly from the onset, I would prefer some aspects of the design be carefully thought out so as to minimize tweaking of things on a fully deployed system.